# Не могу добавить команду help

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Есть команда, которая должна выводить помощь

```
@bot.command()
async def help(ctx):
    embed_help = discord.Embed(title="Помощь:anchor:", description="**Краткий обзор**", color=0xc700c7)
    embed_help.add_field(name="Модули (.help modules)", value="Доступные модули", inline=False)
    embed_help.add_field(name="Справка", value="Узнать о боте — команда .about")
    await ctx.send(embed = embed_help)
```

Запуская бота, появляется консоль и через секунду закрывается. Успел словить фрагментом экрана(Внизу консоль)

[image: console]

Прочитал, что нужно под командой `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = settings['prefix'])` нужно написать `bot.delete_command('help')`. Но так и так консоль закрывается с такой же ошибкой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если не умеете пользоваться документацией, то откройте [**руководство**](https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/using_docs.md#%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9) и в соответствии с инструкцией найдите объект, список свойств и методов которого вам нужно посмотреть.

В данном случае в тексте ошибки сказано, что объект `Bot`, а именно (`discord.ext.commands.Bot`) не имеет метода `delete_command()`. Следовательно, ищем в документации [**этот объект**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot#discord.ext.commands.Bot) и смотрим какие у него есть функции, которые могут быть связаны с удалением встроенной команды. *Если непонятно из названия, листаем и читаем описание.*

### В конечном итоге находим функцию [`remove_command()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot#discord.ext.commands.Bot.remove_command), которая делает то, что вам нужно.